# Add current week flag column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I efficiently and elegantly add current week flag column using SQL query as shown in the picture attached. It has to be True or 1 for the week TODAY falls under. I was thinking of `FIRST_VALUE` and `CASE`. Am I in the right track?

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: What is your definition of "efficiently and elegantly"? Personally I want a practical solution, not one that looks good.

Comment: Dale, simplest and practical solution would work.

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try on the query. Come back when it is not working

Comment: I was able to take a datediff and id 1/5/2023 in above example and with CASE make that current week flag field 1 for 1/5/2023 and 0 for all others. Trying to get flag 1 to remaining six data points 1/1/2023 thru 1/4/2023 and 1/6/2023 thru 1/7/2023?

Comment: Add your attempt to the question... and convert your images to formatted text (Many people ignore questions with images), ideally add your sample data as DDL+DML (or a DBFiddle) so people can easily test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the week number:

```
SELECT IIF(DATEPART(WEEK, GETUTCDATE()) = DATEPART(WEEK, '2023-04-01'), 1, 0)
      ,IIF(DATEPART(WEEK, GETUTCDATE()) = DATEPART(WEEK, '2023-04-03'), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Is week number from datepart an ISO week number?

Comment: @sagar, for ISO week use ISO_WEEK :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your weeks start on Sundays you can choose an early Saturday that doesn't appear in your data and count the whole weeks (7days) since that date:

```
case when datediff(day, cast('1889-12-29' as date), getdate())/7
           =
         datediff(day, cast('1889-12-29' as date), [date])/7
    then 1 
    else 0 
end
```

Comment: Week number is an ISO week.

Comment: @sagar, I guess this comment does not apply to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive example of using `DATEPART()`.
The difference here is it runs DATEPART() only for that week, not your entire dataset.  There is an inferred problem of identifying the same week (number) for the same year, and your sample data contains different years.  The easiest way I can think of is to identify the MAX and MIN date for that week/year.  I use Common Table Expressions (CTEs) and recursion below:

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE(); 
DECLARE @weeknum int = DATEPART(WEEK, @today);
DECLARE @mindate date;
DECLARE @maxdate date;

WITH CTE_date_up AS ( 
 SELECT @today as [dateVal] --base case
 UNION ALL --repetitive case of recursion going up
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [dateVal])       
   FROM CTE_date_up
  WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 1, [dateVal])) = @weeknum
)
,CTE_date_down AS ( 
 SELECT @today as [dateVal] --base case
 UNION ALL --repetitive case of recursion going down
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, [dateVal])
   FROM CTE_date_down
  WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -1, [dateVal])) = @weeknum
)
,CTE_Select as ( --combining the results, and removing the startdate duplicate with UNION
SELECT * FROM CTE_date_up UNION SELECT * FROM CTE_date_down
)

--Setting the @mindate and @maxdate variables
SELECT @mindate = MIN(dateVal)
      ,@maxdate = MAX(dateVal)
  FROM CTE_Select

--At this point @mindate and @maxdate are saved to variables
--In Your query, use the variables in a case statement, ex.
SELECT [date], [week num]
      ,[current week flag] = CASE WHEN [date] BETWEEN @mindate AND @maxdate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM mytable
```